# How enable/disable orientation (rotation) until press UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, orientation

I have an application with 3 tabs in TabBarController. On the first tab, it's possible enable rotation from portrait to landscape just when the user press a button on NavigationBar? The first time the user can not rotate, only when he presses a button.

I'm using SDK iOS 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whose rotation r u talking about?

Comment: @Prince sorry, from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return allowedToRotate;

}
```

Then just have a `BOOL allowedToRotate;` in your class header and set it to YES when you want to allow rotating. If you are on iOS 6:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if (allowedToRotate)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

That should work, though I haven't tried it...

Comment: XCode said that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated on iOS 6. However, I tried that code but doesn't work. I set `return NO` and I still rotate to landscape.

Comment: O yes iOS 6 changed things, I've updated the answer... (tho I haven't actually tried it...)

Comment: In my case, the method supportedInterfaceOrientations is correctly called and it returns UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait. However, when I rotate the device, the user interface rotates as well. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me...not sure if its the best way....but it works:

```
 -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {

// Return YES for supported orientations
return NO;

 }

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
//Setting the orientation of the view.  Ive set it to portrait here.

return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

 }
```

Comment: you just put these methods for override in the CustomControllerView.m file? didn't work for me...